# How to find records exist with one date but not the other within the same table with sql

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table like so:

```
LocationId | CreatedDate | HeadCount
-----------+-------------+-----------
1          | 2017-6-5    | 12
3          | 2017-6-5    | 458
5          | 2017-6-5    | 125
1          | 2017-8-5    | 12
5          | 2017-8-5    | 458
```

I need to find all the LocationIds in the table that exist on a particular date but do not exist in another date. So in the table above I'd need to return

```
3          | 2017-6-5    | 458
```

I'm trying the below, but I think I may need to use temp tables to accomplish my task.

```
SELECT * 
FROM HeadCounts a
FULL OUTER JOIN HeadCounts b ON a.LocationId = b.LocationId
WHERE a.CreatedDate = '2017-6-5'
  AND b.CreatedDate = '2017-6-5'
  AND a.LocationId IS NULL
   OR b.LocationId IS NULL
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is that literally the value stored on `CreatedDate`?  Is it actually being stored like that, as a `VARCHAR`?

Comment: are you interested in two specific dates or just any different dates?

Comment: Three very different answers. All based on guessing here because it is not totally clear what you are trying to do. And the details of your dates are not consistent between your sample data and the attempted query. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with a `WHERE NOT EXISTS`:

```
Select  *
From    HeadCounts  H1
Where Not Exists
(
    Select  *
    From    HeadCounts  H2
    Where   H1.LocationId = H2.LocationId
    And     H1.CreatedDate <> H2.CreatedDate
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you want only those two specific dates you could do something like this.

```
select LocationID
    , MAX(CreatedDate)
    , MAX(HeadCount)
from YourTable
where CreatedDate  in ('2017-6-5', '2017-8-5')
group by LocationID
having count(*) <= 1
```

Comment: @MartinSmith LOL. I just copied them from the OP. :)

Comment: It won't....but the question is not really clear what they want either because in their sample query the "two" dates are the same.

Comment: Who knows....I guessed at the two dates and stuck them back in. Maybe they want specific two dates, maybe they want any two dates....guessing

Answer (score 0):

```
select LocationId, CreatedDate, HeadCount 
from HeadCounts
where LocationId not in(
    select LocationId from HeadCounts
        where locationid in(
            select LocationId from HeadCounts 
            where CreatedDate = '2017-6-5') 
and CreatedDate != '2017-6-5')
```